# The alpha bibliography style doesn't support @thesis - what to do?

Tags: bibtex

I'm using the `alpha` bibliography style in a document. I don't actually *have* to use it, but it seems fitting to what I'm writing. Anyway, one of my bibliographies has some `@thesis { ... }` entries, but `alpha` doesn't like them:

```
Warning--entry type for "Foo2001" isn't style-file defined
```

What should I do?

Comment: Yes... make this an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `alpha` bibliography style provides the entry types `@mastersthesis` and `@phdthesis`. Will one of them work for you?

*Addendum*: Both entry types have the same set of `required` and `optional` fields:

- required: `author`, `title`, `school`, `year`
- optional: `address`, `note`

As always with BibTeX, all fields that are neither required nor optional are silently ignored.

The output of the two entry types differs in that the one says "Master's thesis", whereas the other says "PhD thesis".

This information pertains, incidentally, not just to the `alpha` bibliography style; it also pertains to the `plain`, `unsrt`, and `abbrv` styles, i.e., to the entire set of "original" bib styles shipped with BibTeX since ca 1984.